# What's the closest Node.js equivalent to Rakefiles?

Tags: node.js, shell, makefile, task

I'd like to switch from Makefiles to something more Node-idiomatic, but npm run-scripts can't depend on each other, and grunt makes it incredibly overcomplicated to construct shell tasks.

Is there another Node tool for easily writing dependent shell tasks?

Comment: Well, shell tasks probably aren't idiomatic in themselves, since they'll narrows the supported systems or will have to be written for each varying system. But, generally, you can just mix [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) with [`async`](https://npmjs.org/package/async) or [`q`](https://npmjs.org/package/q) to control when they start.

Comment: What is overcomplicated about Grunt?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it before, Grunt has met my needs but I think Jake might be what you are looking for http://howtonode.org/intro-to-jake